# How to filter most recent 3 data from api - using javascript & react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, timestamp, filtering

I try to show only recent data by using createdAt date. But I can't.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Q3Z.png)

I want to display only the most recent 3 data created last using javascript & react.

[api-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1eLF.png)

Comment: As @Asraf said, hide the API address or block it to public

Comment: can you solve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
response.data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.attributes.createdAt) - new Date(b.attributes.createdAt))[0]
```

But I really recommend doing it in the BackEnd

Edit:
I see now that you are looking for the first 3 responses so you can use the same sorting mechanism and use .slice(0,3)

```
    response.data.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.attributes.createdAt) - new Date(b.attributes.createdAt)).slice(0,3)
```